# Karma test fail with PhantomJS browser with error : Component should be created

Tags: angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, gitlab-ci

I'm using PhantomJS browser to test my angular application to deploy it with continus integration GITLAB-CI.

The tests are going well when using chrome browser. when installing PhantomJS and enabling some imports in polyfills.ts file, the test resut returns :

**SomeComponent should be created.**

I tried using **ChromeHeadless** , but there is a problem with the environment path when testing in **gitlab-ci.**

What can i do to fix it ? or there is another way to do it ?